# Python input if else statement help (in terminal)

Tags: python, input, terminal

I'm having some trouble with some code here.  Its python, and I'm running it in terminal.  Here is the code.

```
def inputPlayerLetter():
    print('Do you want to be X or O?')
    letter = input()
    if letter == "X":
        print "You are now X's, you will go first "
    Player = X
    Computer = O
    else:
        print "You are now O's you will go second"
    Player = O
    Computer = X
```

However, when i start the file in terminal, i get this

```
HHNEs-MacBook-Pro-3:ttt hhneadmin$ python ttt.py
Do you want to be X or O?
X
You are now O's you will go second

HHNEs-MacBook-Pro-3:ttt hhneadmin$ !!
python ttt.py
Do you want to be X or O?
O
You are now O's you will go second
```

Why does it say that when I choose X, I still get the response I get when it should be O. This is probably a stupid question, but I am a beginner with python, so help along with an explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is something you are trying to do:

```
def inputPlayerLetter():
    letter = raw_input('Do you want to be X or O? ')

    if letter == "X":
        print "You are now X's, you will go first"
        Player = 'X'
        Computer = 'O'
    else:
        print "You are now O's you will go second"
        Player = 'O'
        Computer = 'X'

inputPlayerLetter()
```

**Output**

```
Do you want to be X or O? X
You are now X's, you will go first
```

The problem with your code is in `player = X`. Since `X` is not a string, pyhton treats it as a variable and looks for the definition of `X`. And since `X` hasn't been defined anywhere, it raises an exception.